# Duplicate records in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I have an odd issue, I am updating mongo documents using the updateDocument function below,
I see that the collection is getting duplicated with the same "ObjectId"
I discovered this while trying to delete the documents using "mongo chef", some of the documents have ObjectId, some of them don't.

[image: the duplicate list]

[image: the mongo chef removal dialog]

the update code:

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate  mongoTemplate;

public WriteResult updateDocument(DBObject document) {
     DBCollection collection mongoTemplate.getCollection("documents");
     DBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("documentId",documentId)
                      .append("ownerId", ownerId);

collection.update(query, document);
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not "duplication". Some of the data is a "string" and some is `ObjectId`. You have **errant code** which is incorrectly storing as "string". So you need to find that code and "fix it". You can identify the "strings" by querying with `.find({ "_id": { "$type": 2 } })` using [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to identify those documents stored with the incorrect key. The "priority" though should be "fix the code that is doing this".

Comment: So the overall point is the **bad code** is not included in your question. It does **need** to be fixed. And is somewhat worrying because the only way possible to have the same "string" value and the "hex" value of an existing `ObjectId` is by taking a "copy". It simply is not possible that you managed to generate `ObjectId` values with the same hex value as an independent method. These are "copies" and likely from a "malformed" `"upsert"` operation, which is being supplied `_id` as a "string" rather than an `ObjectId`. That's where I would look first.